# OpenGL custom navigation/selection

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

I have a situation that I'm not realy sure how I can handle. I have an openGl object of about 20k vertices, and I need to offer the user the possibility to select any one of these vertices (let's say with a smallest margin of error possible). Now here is what I want to do in order to do this:

Next to the 3D canvas of the object, I also offer the user 3 'slices' done by the planes x=0; y=0 and z=0. Say for the simplest example for a sphere these would be 3 circles, correponding to 'cutting' out one of the dimensions. Now let's take the z=0 one for the purpose of the example. When the user clicks on a point say (x_circle, y_circle) i would like to get the actual point in the 3d representation where he clicked. The z would be 0 of course but I can't figure out a way to get the x and y. I can easily translate that `(x_circle, y_circle) -> (x_screen, y_screen)` which would have the same result as a click on the canvas at those coordinates, but I need to find a way to translate that into the (x, y, 0) coordinate in 3D view.

The same thing would need to be done with x=0, y=0 but I think if I can understand/implement a way for z=0 I can just apply more or less the same solution with an added rotation over something. If anyone can help with any examples/code or even math behind this it would help a lot because at the moment I'm not really sure how to proceed.

Comment: You need to unproject screen coordinates, giving you view coordinates in the scene, and then find the first vertex that intersects (or is close within your threshold) to the ray from that point.  So keywords to look for on google are Picking, gluUnProject, Distance Between Line and Point, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But from what I see gluUnProject turns 3d -> 3d. I really only need to turn 2d -> 2d, since on screen I only have x,y and in openGL coordinates I already know i want from the plane z=0.

Comment: I guess you're thinking in 2D still. The screen is a flat plane at the near Z buffer value.  So in view space Z = Zmin is the screen plane.  So your point on the screen at x, y is really x, y, Zmin in 3D.  Now you still need to determine where the other end of the ray should be, i.e. the direction from x, y, Zmin your mouse cursor is pointing into the scene.  You can do this by applying the inverse of the view matrix.

Answer (score 2):

When the user clicks, you can render the vertices using GL.POINTS (with a certain size, if you like) to an off-screen buffer using a shader that renders each vertex' index into RGBA. Then you read back the pixel on the mouse position and see what index it is.